# MapView black screen but no errors in Android

Tags: java, android, android-mapview

I am trying to display a location with a MapView but I can't get it to work.
I have already look into all the other threads with the same questions but the solutions don't work for me.

Here is what is supposed to work but doesn't:

```
    public void displayMap(){
    final MapView mapView = findViewById(R.id.locationMapView);
    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            LatLng coordinates = new LatLng(14.0583, 108.2772); //for testing
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(coordinates).title("Test"));
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinates, 15));
        }
    });
}
```

I am new to Android Studio and just trying things out. 
I also already tried to comprehend the reference/documentation but it was not that helpful because I don't really get where to start.

I'd be very thankful if someone explained the mistake to me.
Of course, if I missed important information you need I'll get it for you.

edit1:

this is the logcat

https://pastebin.com/qMKzsQQS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stopped trying to implement this as a MapView and switched to a MapAcitvity.
Implementing this is much easier it seems, just create "new-> Google-> Map Activity" in Android Studio

I think the issue with my approach was that I didn't know where to put the api key. 
although it didnt thow an error concerning this...

EDIT:

Here is the solution / an example of how I got it to work:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MapView mMap = findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMap.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMap.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    MapView mMap = findViewById(R.id.map);
    super.onStart();
    mMap.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    MapView mMap = findViewById(R.id.map);
    super.onResume();
    mMap.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    MapView mMap = findViewById(R.id.map);
    super.onPause();
    mMap.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    MapView mMap = findViewById(R.id.map);
    super.onStop();
    mMap.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    MapView mMap = findViewById(R.id.map);
    super.onLowMemory();
    mMap.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    MapView mMap = findViewById(R.id.map);
    super.onDestroy();
    mMap.onDestroy();
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    LatLng Test = new LatLng(50, 9);
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition( new CameraPosition.Builder().target(Test).zoom(15.0f).build()),20000, null);

}
```

I won't include the xml code, as it is just a fill_parent mapView called "map".

I put the API Key in the AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
 android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

I think thats it.
Thanks for the help and tips!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

I think that the possible pitfall is that you need to call `mapView.onResume(bundle)`, `mapView.onPause()`, etc. in your Fragment/Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance)
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstance)
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mapView.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mapView.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}
```

You can read about it in the [MapView's documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView).

Also, see the logs. You could see some warnings from Google Maps SDK regarding wrong API Key, or related.

Comment: I'll try and get back to you, thank you for the answer

Comment: Don't forget the `onCreate`. Which also needs to be called. This is important because the MapView can use a lot of resources, and by being aware of the whole lifecycle, it can manage memory usage better.

It requires some lifecycle calls to start-up in the first place.

Comment: Also, read this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map-with-marker

You can also use a SupportMapFragment insead of MapView. But this is up to you. As far as I know, there's not right option in this.

Comment: I did add all the methods and am now getting a Nullpointer Exception'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()'

Comment: Please edit your question with the stacktrace and updated source code

Comment: I didn't really fix the issue but thanks to the link you provided I switched to just creating a new activity instead of the mapView

Answer (score 0):

your API key is not enabled , [visit this site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) to know how to get a api key

Comment: I got an API Key and I added it to the androidmanifest.xml, there would be an error in the logcat if that hadn't worked, right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to to have available Google maps sdk android.
Go to the link and active it .
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/maps-android-backend.googleapis.com/